# Eigenvalues of the integral equation $\int_{-T}^{+T}\exp(-\alpha|t-u|)\phi(u)du=\lambda\phi(t)$

Tags: integral-equations

I've been going through 'Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory 2e' by Van Trees et al and am having trouble with Problem 6.4.1:

> Consider the integral equation
> $$\int_{-T}^{+T}\exp\left(-\alpha|t-u|\right)\phi(u)\mathrm{d}u=\lambda\phi(u).$$
> a) Prove that $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=2/\alpha$ are not eigenvalues.

I can't see the best way to do this. If we do a change of coordinates $\alpha u=u'$, we can re-write the left-hand side as
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\left[\int_{-\alpha T}^t\exp\left(-(t'-u')\right)\phi(u')\mathrm{d}u'+\int_t^{\alpha T}\exp\left(-(u'-t')\right)\phi(u')\mathrm{d}u'\right],$$
and it reduces to showing that the quantity in square brackets may not have eigenvalues $0$ or $2$, but I don't know how much that helps.

There is also a part b:

> b) Prove that all values of $\lambda>2/\alpha$ cannot be eigenvalues of the integral equation.

but I am hoping that once I understand how to approach a), it will be clearer how to approach this.

Comment: What's the underlying vector space?

Comment: We want $\phi(u)$ to be a square-integrable function.

Comment: For people arriving in the future, a good solution to this problem may be found in Example 1, Chapter 2.4 of Zemyan "The Classical Theory of Integral Equations". The entire book is overall quite excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $\alpha >0$ and we are looking for continuous solutions.

Let's define $f$ as
$$f(x)=\exp(-\alpha|x|)$$
In this case, the equation can be written as
$$(f*\phi [-T,T])(x)=\lambda \phi(x)[-T,T](x)$$
With arbitrary extension outside $[-T,T]$. If we make it $0$ there, we can abandon the indicator function, i.e.:
$$(f*\phi)(x)=\lambda \phi(x)$$
If we are looking for continuous solutions (we can loosen this assumption), we can take the Fourier-transform of both sides:
$$\hat{f}(\omega)\hat{\phi}(\omega)=\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}\hat{\phi}(\omega)=\lambda \hat{\phi}(\omega)$$
I.e.
$$\hat{\phi}(\omega)\left(\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}-\lambda\right)=0$$
One of the terms need to be zero for all $\omega$. So let's look for the zeroes of the second expression:
$$\frac{2\alpha}{\lambda}-\alpha^2=\omega^2$$
i.e.
$$\omega = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2\alpha}{\lambda}-\alpha^2}$$
Which has a solution if
$$\frac{2\alpha}{\lambda}-\alpha^2\geqslant 0$$
i.e.
$$\lambda \leqslant \frac{2}{\alpha}$$
Buf if $\lambda =\frac{2}{\alpha}$, we only have one solution: $\omega=0$, so only $\hat{\phi}(0)$ can be non-zero.

To rule out the $\lambda=0$ possibility, we could use an orthonormal series in $L^2$ and derive that all of the coefficients of $\phi$ must be zero, but I wouldn't do it, because I don't like the absolute value in the integrals. But if we substitute $\lambda=0$ into the equation in the Fourier space, we get that
$$\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2+\omega^2}=0$$
Which does not have a solution unless $\alpha=0$.

**Edit:**  Clearly, there are some flaws in the answer, but I think the idea is not bad: the Fourier transform gives us an algebraic equation ehich reveals the possible eigenvalues. It also reveals that the solution (with the extension and cutoff) cannot be continuous, because the Fourier-equation gives us $2$ possible non-zero value, which is a measure-zero set (and the FT of a continuous function is continuous). The solution might need distributions and/or a better cutoff.

Comment: Thanks very much, I think the most important point is there, that since there is a convolution we need to move to the Fourier basis, and the algebraic constraint you derive places the appropriate bounds on the eigenvalue. We do have this strange behaviour where $\lambda$ depends on $\omega$, but I think that's because $\hat{\phi}(\omega)$ is in fact a sum of $\delta$-functions ($\phi(t)$ is a cosine function), so $\lambda$ will end up being a constant.

Comment: @RuviLecamwasam I think it's normal that $\lambda$ depends on $\omega$. In the case of the negative differential operator squared, the eigenvalue is the square root of the frequency of the solution (i.e. $u(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)$ satisfies $-D^2u=\omega^2 u$).